# How do I increment the value of a variable by 1 every 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var addTime = function() {
    var time = 1;
    setInterval((function() {
      time = time + 1;
    }), 3000);
    console.log(time);
  };
  addTime();
});
```

Right now, it only outputs `2`. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are just doing one output? If you want to see the increment each time, move the `console.log()` inside the `setInterval()` callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is being incremented. But it's printed only once.

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var addTime = function() {
    var time = 1;
    setInterval((function() {
      time = time + 1;
      console.log(time);
    }), 3000);

  };
  addTime();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Below javascript function would help you.

```
window.setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);
```

And here is the sample code

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer()
{
   // code you want to execute
}
```

You can also refer the Jquery Timer..below is the link
http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo

Here are the multiple options available

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
                alert('This message was sent by a timer.');
        });

        timer.set({ time : 5000, autostart : true });

        timer.set(options);
        timer.play(reset);  // Boolean. Defaults to false.
        timer.pause();
        timer.stop();  // Pause and resets
        timer.toggle(reset);  // Boolean. Defaults to false.
        timer.once(time);  // Number. Defaults to 0.
        timer.isActive  // Returns true if timer is running
        timer.remaining // Remaining time when paused
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?